# Can Datanucleus SchemaTool create additional columns not bound to a PC but mapped in JDO ORM?

Tags: orm, jdo, datanucleus

I have a User class (@PC) currently having only one property: 'email', now I want the user-table (where User class is stored) to have additional columns, which are not managed by JDO but are subject of authentication happening outside of PM. When I auto-create the table by Datanucleus and then ALTER the table adding my columns everything works as expected.

Of course I would be happy to use SchemaTool for generation/update of the schema, yet dont want to have manual ALTER table procedure on that user table. Naively I've tried to put the two extra columns into ORM file (omitting targets):

```xml
  <package name="bo">
    <class name="User" table="tb_user">
      <column name="USER_SECURITY" jdbc-type="VARCHAR" length="64"/>
      <column name="SEC_SALT" jdbc-type="VARCHAR" length="10"/>
    </class>
  </package>
```

but SchemaTool did not generate the extra columns, altough ORM file was loaded according to logs.

BTW: no way I want to have those columns mapped and managed during JDO lifecycle.

so, is it possible to get Schematool to generate extra columns on tables or do I have to sort them out into another table not managed by Datanucleus?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDO spec defines such as that as seen in this link, and I have no problem with our tests using such unmapped columns in SchemaTool
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_3/jdo/orm/schema_mapping.html#unmapped

Comment: tx for the link! There's is no issue if I move the column definition from .orm into a .jdo file but SchemaTool ignores that definition from an .orm file, EVEN THOUGH the table-name defined in .orm file WINs over that defined in .jdo file (like expected) but unmapped columns are fully ignored in .orm, thanks anyway

Comment: why not report it in the issue tracker ? maybe some issue around merging the ORM metadata into the JDO metadata